# Is this equation separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation:

$dy/dx=4y^2-3y+1$

From what I can tell, this is NOT separable because there is no g(x) on the right side.  Does that look right?  It doesn't factor either.

Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=1\cdot(4y^2-3y+1) \longrightarrow \frac{\mathrm dy}{4y^2-3y+1}=1\cdot \mathrm dx=\mathrm dx$

Comment: As a brief aside, wolframalpha gives $\int \frac{\mathrm dy}{4y^2-3y+1}=\large \frac{2 \arctan(\frac{8y-3}{\sqrt 7})}{\sqrt 7}$

Answer (score 0):

Equations in the form $\frac {dy}{dx} = f(x)g(y)$ are called separable and solved by $\frac {dy}{g(y)} = f(x)dx$ and thus $\int\frac {dy}{g(y)} = \int f(x)dx$. Prior to dividing by $g(y)$, one needs to check if there are stationary (also called equilibrium) solutions $y=\text{const}$ satisfying $g(y)=0$.

In your case $f(x)=1$ and $g(y)=4y^2-3y+1\ne 0$ (the roots are complex).